# After installing Ubuntu 13.04 blank screen "Missing operating system"

Tags: installation, 13.04

I'm switching back to Ubuntu after a long hiatus. I used it for a couple of years in college so I thought I knew what I was doing. However, after burning the 13.04 64 bit ISO to a DVD on Windows 7, booting it and following the on screen installation instructions, I am now greeted with a blank screen that only says "Missing operating system" when I boot up my computer. I checked my boot order and my SSD that's supposed to have Ubuntu on it is first priority. I've tried reinstalling it a couple times, including one time when I went in manually, selected "New partition table" on my SSD, formatted the disk, and then created a swap and root partition, which I installed Ubuntu to. I'm still getting the "Missing operating system" message. I know the OS is on there because when I go into the installer it says that Ubuntu is installed. Am I missing something? I also have a second hard drive that just has videos and music on it formatted in NTFS, but I don't think this has anything to do with it because I made sure the installer only went to work on my SSD. Any help would be greatly appreciated, this is my main machine so I want to get it working as soon as possible. Thank you in advance.

My specs are as follows:
- UEFI capable ASRock P67 Extreme4 motherboard
- Intel Core i5 2500k Sandy Bridge processor
- nVidia 580 GTX 3GB
- G.SKILL Ripjaws X Series 8GB DDR3 1600 RAM
- Crucial M4 128GB SSD
- 1TB Samsung HDD

Comment: Perhaps check the boot order, make sure that the disks are being 'seen' in the correct order. (probably not this, but worth a look!). NTFS should not cause a problem.

Comment: I've checked and double checked my boot order in my BIOS, my SSD with Ubuntu on it is first priority.

Comment: OK, so it looks like Grub is not looking in the correct place. if you remove the 1Tb disk, does it load then?

Comment: I'm not really in a position to open up my computer and disconnect things, being it's the middle of the night and I have a roommate sleeping right next to me. Sorry for the stupid question, but what is Grub and how do I access and configure it? Google is turning up arcane links.

Comment: Grub is the boot manager. it checks all hard drives for operating Systems then displays a menu for you to choose which one you want to start. You can edit it from the Grub Menu and it should be accessible by pressing and hold **Shift** after the BIOS screen.

Comment: Holding shift down does nothing. It goes from the BIOS screen directly to "Missing operating system," there doesn't seem to be anything in between. It's like my computer isn't even attempting to read my SSD at all.

Comment: I go back to my previous post. I think you'll have remove or disable the 1Tb HDD - Perhaps you could remove it from the Boot section all together - That may be as effective.

Comment: Also, run the Boot Info Script from your live CD and post a link to the RESULTS.txt file that it generates (I will not help me, but it may help someone else!) EDIT: visit https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair#A2nd_option_%3a_install_Boot-Repair_in_Ubuntu

Comment: Ok, here's what I just did. I went into the BIOS and deselected my 1TB HDD as a boot device. In fact, I disabled everything but my SSD as a boot device. I then launched the installer again, went into the drive partition screen, selected my HDD and then selected "do not use this partition" with every partition associated with it. I then reformatted my SSD again, set it up with a swap and root partition, and reinstalled Ubuntu. I'm still getting "Missing operating system."

Comment: Also I just tried that link you posted. After connecting to the internet and typing in those commands into the Terminal, I get an error saying "Cannot access PPA, please check your internet connection."

Comment: Sorry, I finally went to bed. it was 6 am! That's really strange. I have just downloaded it and ran boot repair as indicated... I'll take a look around and see if I can think of anything else. **Try entering `sudo parted -l` in to the Terminal window. paste the results in to your original question**.

Comment: Thanks for all your help so far. I just tried entering "sudo parted -1" into the terminal and I get "parted: invalid option -- '1' usage: parted [-hlmsv [-a<align>] [DEVICE [COMMAND [PARAMETERS]]...]"

Comment: that should be a lowercase L not 1 :)

Comment: Ok, I just tried again and I got a read out. However, I can't open Firefox in the Live CD, it just freezes and crashes everything. But I did see that it thought that my 1TB drive had a 100MB swap, an additional 1000MB of space and was flagged as boot. So that must be the problem. How do I switch the boot drive to my SSD?

Comment: If you install gparted from the App Store and run that, it allows you to Change the partition sizes.

Comment: I've tried opening the App Store a couple times. Like every other application other than the terminal, it locks up, crashes and the screen turns black. Is there a way I could do this through the installer? I'm able to play around with partitions with that. How would I delete these two small partitions on my HDD and "reintegrate" them with the rest of the drive, so to speak? And then how could I make sure that the SDD is set to be the boot drive? Sorry for all the questions, and thank you so much for your help. I'm going to work now so I won't be back until about 10PM US Eastern. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

OK. Thought that the conversation was getting a little long, so to install via Terminal, type:

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

in to Terminal then

```
gparted
```

to run